# HTML web page in PDF

Tags: php

I want to know that how to import a html page in creation of a pdf file using FPDF. If there is another option then please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @PedrodelSol i tried to make pdf file which is import the html page as to display in pdf view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vasu you might want to take a look at [HTML2PDF](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=html2pdf&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://html2pdf.fr/en/default&ei=jGkjUehQpMjRBfG-gcgD&usg=AFQjCNEG020eRK2F9gSaqqUQjSnd7hByOw&bvm=bv.42553238,d.d2k).

I've used it for multiple projects and it's quite easy to set up using their documentation.

It allows you give the class HTML in a string and it will generate a PDF based on that.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF conversion, it will help you.

[HTML to PDF Converter](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you **FOP library** http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/.

I've never used with HTML, but may be you can transform your HTML content to a XML structure and, after that, transform it to a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), its very simple to use, and have a great documentation and samples.